# Two problem related to onto linear transformation and its associated matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: \mathbb V \to \mathbb W$ be an onto linear transformation with associated matrix $[F]$, with respect to some bases of $\mathbb V,\mathbb W $. Then:

1. $\dim(\mathbb V) > \dim(\mathbb W)$
2. $Fx = b$ has a solution for any vector $b$.

I think (2) is a true because there is epimorphism, but can someone check this please? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you know Rank–nullity theorem?

Comment: Number 1 should be $dim(V) \geq dim(W)$. Number 2 is true as long as $b \in W$.

Answer (score 0):

Statement (1) is false.

Yes, statement (2) is indeed true.  The manner in which you would prove this depends on what your definition is and what basic knowledge can be assumed for linear epimorphisms.